# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in in json

Tags: php, json

```html
<?php


$json= '{
        "fields" : 
        [
            {
              "name" : "news_title",
              "type" : "text",
              "value" : "old title"
            },
            {
              "name" : "news_content",
              "type" : "textarea",
              "value" : "old content"
            }
        ]            
  }';
 
echo $json;
  $jsonInPHP = json_decode($json,true);
    $results = count($jsonInPHP['fields']);
 for ($r = 0; $r < $results; $r++){
    // look for the entry we are trying to find
    if ($jsonInPHP->fields[$r]['name'] == 'news_title'
     && $jsonInPHP->fields[$r]->value == 'old title'){
      // remove the match
      unset($jsonInPHP->fields[$r]);
    if(empty($jsonInPHP->fields[$r]->value))
 {
  $jsonInPHP['fields'][$r]['name'] == 'news_title';
  $jsonInPHP->fields[$r]->value=='no';
 }
      break;
    }
 
  }
  function gog($status)
  {
     $results = count($status->fields);
 for ($r = 0; $r < $results; $r++){
  $status->fields[$r]->value == 'old rr';
  }
  }
    $jsonInPHP->fields = array_values($jsonInPHP->fields);
   echo json_encode($jsonInPHP);




?>
```

i want to change after searching from

> > '{"fields":[{"name":"news_title","type":"text","value":"old title"},{"name":"news_content","type":"textarea","value":"old content"}]}'

to

> > '{"fields":[{"name":"news_title","type":"text","value":"My new title"},{"name":"news_content","type":"textarea","value":"My new content"}]}'

Comment: The second parameter in PHP turns the object in to an associative array as such you don't need to use `->` and it might be better to consider a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check official docs of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) Second parameter of function `json_decode($json,true);` (in your case `true`) determines whether result will be converted to associative array. If you want to use result as objects set that value to `false` or better omit that at all.